# Use Wordpress Built In Jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript, headers, wp-head

I see that on every page Wordpress is loading in jquery, how do I go about using that jquery as it keeps telling me that it doesn't recognize `$` or `$noConflict();` - I'm trying to add some jquery under `wp_head()`.

Comment: You could start by checking the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery object is `jQuery` rather than `$`. See [noConflict wrappers in `wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) for some examples.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
});
```

Comment: I can't make `$` universal? I have to keep wrapping my custom JS around the alias.

Comment: you could reassign it via `$ = jQuery;`, but you'll only introduce potential conflicts, and as you can see from the example above you only need to reference `jQuery` for the `ready` function and pass the `$` as argument, where you can freely use `$` within.